# Xamarin Android wear watchviewstub template

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have a large Android project that I am trying to convert over to C# using Xamarin, however, when dealing with the Android wear app, there seems to be no way of creating a new layout file in Visual Studio or Xamarin Studio that creates three files like in Android Studio (Main.axml, RectMain.axml, RoundMain.axml). I tried to make a custom item template, but Visual Studio does not show it in the add new item menu. 
I have tried all of the commands, like devenv /InstallVSTemplates 
Any help to figure out a way to automatically generate a layout file with a WatchViewStub and the two corresponding screen type files would be helpful.

Comment: Have you tried the `Android` \ `App` \ `Wear App` template? It creates three layouts:  `Main`, `RectangeMain`, `RoundMain`

Comment: Yes, it does do that, but if I want to add any additional layouts to the project. Doing Android/App/Wear app makes a new wear project, and I just want to add a layout to my project.